# Does the y label need to be of a specific type for SVM to work?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am struggling with an SVM classifier to classify images of dominoes according to their class, for example 1x3.

I have 2.000+ images of 28 different classes of dominoes (can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s5f38k4l2on5mba/AACNQgXuw1edwEb6oO1w3CfOa?dl=0)).

I am running the following script using scikit-learn and SVM as algorithm:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import os # Working with files and folders
from PIL import Image # Image processing

rootdir = os.getcwd()

image_file = 'images.npy'
key_file = 'keys.npy'

if (os.path.exists(image_file) and os.path.exists(key_file)):
  print "Loading existing numpy's"
  pixel_arr = np.load(image_file)
  key = np.load(key_file)
else:
  print "Creating new numpy's"  
  key_array = []
  pixel_arr = np.empty((0,10000), "uint8")

  for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('data'):
    dir_name = subdir.split("/")[-1]    
    if "x" in dir_name:
      for file in files:
        if ".DS_Store" not in file:
          im = Image.open(os.path.join(subdir, file))
          if im.size == (100,100):            
            key_array.append(dir_name)          
            numpied_image = np.array(im.convert('L')).reshape(1,-1)
            #Image.fromarray(np.reshape(numpied_image,(-1,100)), 'L').show()
            pixel_arr = np.append(pixel_arr, numpied_image, axis=0)
          im.close()

  key = np.array(key_array)
  np.save(image_file, pixel_arr)
  np.save(key_file, key)


# Create a classifier: a support vector classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma='auto')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pixel_arr, key, test_size=0.1,random_state=33)

# We learn the digits on the first half of the digits
print "Fitting classifier"
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Now predict the value of the digit on the second half:
expected = y_test

print "Predicting"
predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)

print("Classification report for classifier %s:\n%s\n"
      % (classifier, metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted)))
print("Confusion matrix:\n%s" % metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
```

which yields the following:

```
Classification report for classifier SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False):
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0x0       0.00      0.00      0.00         9
        1x0       0.00      0.00      0.00         9
        1x1       0.00      0.00      0.00        12
        2x0       0.00      0.00      0.00        12
        2x1       0.00      0.00      0.00        10
        2x2       0.00      0.00      0.00         7
        3x0       0.00      0.00      0.00         7
        3x1       0.00      0.00      0.00         8
        3x2       0.00      0.00      0.00         8
        3x3       0.01      1.00      0.02         3
        4x0       0.00      0.00      0.00        11
        4x1       0.00      0.00      0.00        10
        4x2       0.00      0.00      0.00         8
        4x3       0.00      0.00      0.00        15
        4x4       0.00      0.00      0.00         8
        5x0       0.00      0.00      0.00        12
        5x1       0.00      0.00      0.00         7
        5x2       0.00      0.00      0.00        11
        5x3       0.00      0.00      0.00         7
        5x4       0.00      0.00      0.00         9
        5x5       0.00      0.00      0.00        14
        6x0       0.00      0.00      0.00        11
        6x1       0.00      0.00      0.00        12
        6x2       0.00      0.00      0.00        11
        6x3       0.00      0.00      0.00         9
        6x4       0.00      0.00      0.00         9
        6x5       0.00      0.00      0.00        18
        6x6       0.00      0.00      0.00        13

avg / total       0.00      0.01      0.00       280


>>> print("Confusion matrix:\n%s" % metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
Confusion matrix:
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 14  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 18  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0]]
```

Obviously something is very wrong. Even if the classifier would guess freely it would get a better precision! My suspicion, that I haven't been able to confirm is that the way I have created the key/y label is not ok. Still, the script runs without errors but without being able to predict anything.

One thing that leads me to think that there is something wrong with the key is that the confusion matrix does not have any labels.

What could be a possible error when you get results like this?

Edit: I tried using a LabelEncoder on the `key` but the results were the same.

Edit2: I also tried different lambdas and a manually set lambda at 0.00001 something turned out to give a classifier score of 0.05 (which was an improvement compared to the above). I don't expect the classifier to be perfect on this data but I would at least expect something in the realm of 60-70%, not 5%.

Comment: From this confusion matrix, it appears that you're only predicting class 10. For everything. I would start by making sure your classes are all represented in the training data, and check the class balance of your labels

Comment: could you share the remaining pictures.. only 4 types in the dataset linked.

Comment: Christian. I will! I uploaded all of them but apparently the upload was stopped for some reason. They are uploading right now but it may take some time.

Comment: I would also be interested in any feedback regarding other parts of the code. Such as if there is nowhere near enough data, if the arrays are too big (10.000 each) etc. and anything related to that (and possibly what I should research to improve.

Answer (score 0):

For classification problem you should convert target vector first (key) into numerical type instead using directly categories / label names. 
Like in the following example:

```
In [21]: iris=datasets.load_iris()

In [22]: X=iris.data

In [23]: y=iris.target

In [24]: y
Out[24]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

In [25]: iris.target_names
Out[25]: array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], dtype='<U10')
```

Try the following code using mentioned LabelEncoder:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(key)
le.transform(key)
Out[36]: array([0, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks, I added an edit about trying that (in fact, I did before your answer). Unfortunately, I still got the same results.

Comment: Please check  values in target vector stored in variable key

Comment: Yes, I am not sure that images are properly binarized.

Comment: Thanks again. I am, however, not entirely sure what you mean. Did you see my comment about trying this and that it did not work (or cause any positive effect). I have implemented it just in case - and as this is how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't been able to make it work on the script, I used the handwritten images dataset and applied this script and it gave the same results. It did however end up working better **with other gamma values**. I.e. at first all the results were in the middle but with changing of the gamma I got the handwritten digits-script to get a great precision. I can only assume it is the same issue here, although I haven't been able to find a gamma value that gives anything better than 5% precision.

But, as to why this happens, I am quite certain that the gamma value (or perhaps any other parameter of the SVC) is off.

Comment: have you testet on the mnist dataset?

Comment: I tested it in the scikit-learn dataset (which I think is the same).

Comment: I can't get any better than 10% with a lot of configuration. I believe maybe that the data (images) are too different. It can't pick up on the dots in the dominoes - I believe the rotation, zoom, background etc adds too much noise. I am currently thinking of how I can manipulate the data to create more versions of each image (rotated etc).

Comment: maybe create a black and white one?

Comment: I did that first, but that transformation was quite noisy. At the moment I am using grayscale. I believe it removes the effect of the background.

Comment: (I retried with BW but got back to 1% precision as opposed to 10% with grayscale). I believe the noise speckles are similar sized to the domino dots.

Comment: Hi! Try another kernel for example: classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='poly') gives better results.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the poly kernel how ever just kept on running forever (over 15 mins instead of a few secs)